# react typescript error - element implicitly has an any type because expression of type string cant be used to index type {}

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to group an array by x in my react project using typescript and getting the following error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.  TS7053
```

Can someone help me define this so it removes the typescript error?  I am completely new to React.

here is the location of the error

```
const result = trades.reduce((groupedAccounts, trade) => {
  const account = trade.pacct;
  if (groupedAccounts[account] == null) groupedAccounts[account] = [];
  groupedAccounts[account].push(trade);
  return groupedAccounts;
}, {});
```

here is my export interface from another .ts

```
    export interface TradeData {
  id: number;
  filedate: Date;
  poffic: string;
  pacct: string;
  quantity: number;
  sector: string;
  psdsC1: string;
  name: string;
  bbsymbol: string;
  last_price: number;
  deltasettlement: number;
}
```

I'm sure its a syntax issue I just don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reduce` can take a generic to specify what the predicate returns (and the type of the initial value).

Here it is inferred as `{}` because of the initial value:

```
const result = trades.reduce((groupedAccounts, trade) => {
  const account = trade.pacct;
  if (groupedAccounts[account] == null) groupedAccounts[account] = [];
  groupedAccounts[account].push(trade);
  return groupedAccounts;
}, {});
```

You probably want it to be `Record<string, TradeData[]>`:

```
const result = trades.reduce<Record<string, TradeData[]>>((groupedAccounts, trade) => {
  const account = trade.pacct;
  if (groupedAccounts[account] == null) groupedAccounts[account] = [];
  groupedAccounts[account].push(trade);
  return groupedAccounts;
}, {});
```

Comment: thank you!  this worked. Record<string,TradeData[]>.  I understand the <string,TradeData[]>, but what does the 'RECORD' mean?  what is this and what does it do?

Comment: Personally, I would assert the type on the argument itself, rather than specifying in the type arguments explicitly. `trades.reduce((groupedAccounts, trade) => ..., {} as Record<string, TradeData[]>)`

Comment: @solarissf: A [record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) is just a type that maps keys to values. In this case, `string` to `TradeData[]`.

Comment: thank you. both seem to work.  why would assert type on argument itself, rather than in type arguments?

Comment: Preference. I actually also use an assertion on the initial value argument.